# Error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() al hacer insert multiple laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola como estan? estoy tratando de hacer un insert de multiples filas en una tabla, el codigo que estoy tratando de implementar en el controlador es este:

```
public function store(Request $request){
       // dd($request->all());
      foreach($request->despacho_id as $key=>$despacho_id){
        $rebaja = new RebajaFerreteriaTecnico();
        $rebaja->despacho_id = $despacho_id;
        $rebaja->cantidad = $request->cantidad[$key];

        $rebaja->stock_bodega_tecnico_id = $request->stock_bodega_tecnico_id[$key];
        $rebaja->tecnico_id = $request->tecnico_id[$key];

        $rebaja->save();


    }
}
```

pero me da el error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Como se ve en la imagen, recibo bien en los array los datos que necesito (los que estan en null es porque aun no los quito del formulario)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera que [`foreach(){..........}`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) solamente va a funcionar sobre:

- arrays
- objetos

Dado eso entonces es válido que tu código no ande pues como observas: `despacho_id` es un string que almacena un valor numérico.

Lo que procede en este caso sería:

- Hacer un `dd` al contenido de `$request` para evaluar el contenido recibido e identificar aquello que esta quedando faltante
- Si del *front* va a llegar un *array* de elementos, entonces tal vez falta que revises si el atributo `name` tiene una sintaxis como esta: `name="despachos[]"`
- Una vez identificado o establecido y enviado el array que contiene la data válida será esa misma estructura la que deberás iterar